# getting maven to use repository for one library only

Tags: maven

i have a repository setup like this

```
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository> 
        <id>itextpdf.com</id> 
        <name>Maven Repository for iText</name> 
        <url>http://maven.itextpdf.com/</url>
    </repository>
```

how do i set up the dependency to use the itext repository only for itext and jboss for everything else.  for some reason the dependencies are being downloaded by both and one of them that is in the itext repository is different than the jboss and is crashing my system.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this if the artifact only exists in one of the repositories (maven will try each repository in order and will stop once it finds it). The itext repo doesn't have any of the jboss jars so listing it first should result in it being checked first (and when it fails to resolve the jboss jars, it'll try the jboss repo).

Alternatively, if you have your own Maven repository server (Nexus, for instance), acting as a proxy for the public maven repositories, you can set up a "Repository Routing" in which you tell it which repositories to search for specific artifacts (based on group ID).

Comment: yea, thats how i thought it worked as well, but when i go thru my build logs i see its downloading the file from jboss, then downloading it a second time from itext.  i want to try to eliminate this second download.

Comment: Is it actually downloading from jboss? if you browse the repo, the itext directory is empty (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/itext/itext/1.5.2/ gives an error). Try reversing the order in which you declared the repos (declare itext first) to have it try that one before the jboss repository.

Comment: yea, according to my logs its downloading the file from both places.  doesn't matter much anymore, i fixed it with a different route